# Sending JMS message immediately disregarding current TX status

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-transactions, spring-jms

in short, I use super simple JMS configuration taken from spring *Getting Started* guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/.

My case is that I'd like to send JMS message from transactional method even if TX is failed, sth like (kotlin code) :

```
@Service
open class MyService(private val t: JmsTemplate) {
//
  @Transactional
  open fun go(sth: String) {
    val result = // some logic here
    t.convertAndSend("NeedsToBeDelivered", result)
    // more logic which might fail
  }
}
```

Result is delivered only if TX is successful, if not - *more logic section fails* - the msg is lost.
I was trying to configure AMQ in many different ways, also tried several TX variants but none of the works for me.

I'm interested in 
1/ delivery disregarding tx status
2/ immediate delivery (not postponed until current TX finishes).

Suggestions?

**UPDATE**

Yesterday I tried this one and works as expected.

```
 @Transactional(propagation = NOT_SUPPORTED)
 fun sendNoTx(msg: String, destination: String) = try {
    val con = cf.createConnection() // cf stands for connection factory
    con.start()
    val session = con.createSession(false, AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE)
    val producer = session.createProducer(session.createQueue(destination))
    producer.send(session.createTextMessage(msg))
    con.close()
 } catch (e: Exception) {
    LOG.warn("Failed to send NO TX message", e)
 }
```

More elegant solution suggested by Gary is to feed JmsTemplate with another instance of CF - having it done this way we avoid all *conn.close()*-like mess and exception handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use 2 connection factories so that the `JmsTemplate` does not participate in the listener container's transaction.

The template does a lookup for a transactional resource (the session) keyed on the connection factory.

If it has a different connection factory it won't find it and will use its own session instead.